# Run VBA macro in Excel sheet using external c# console application

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am trying to invoke one macro which is in Excel file.
Below is the code which I got, but on running below it throws exception, with below message.

Code:

```
// Define your Excel Objects
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;

try
{
    //Start Excel and open the workbook.
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\MyFolder\Junk\macro\xxxxxReport.xlsm");

    //Run the macros by supplying the necessary arguments
    xlApp.Run("LookupHLink");

    //xlWorkBook.Save();
    //Clean-up: Close the workbook
    xlWorkBook.Close(false);

    //Quit the Excel Application
    xlApp.Quit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    //~~> Clean Up
    releaseObject(xlApp);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
}
```

There is no parameter for the macro.

```
Public Sub LookupHLink()
```

Error message:

> Cannot run the macro 'LookupHLink'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Is the sub in a regular module or in a Sheet module?  If the latter then you may need to use (eg) `xlApp.Run("Sheet1.LookupHLink");` where `Sheet1` is the name of the worksheet module.

Comment: Tried that also but error again :Cannot run the macro 'XXXX_Detail.LookupHLink'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the possible causes of this error are:

- The system located the file but could not load it.
- The file was loaded but it has no macros.
- The file was loaded but the macros are disabled.
- The file was loaded, macros exists... but you misspelled the name.

Given the available information, it seems to be that the more likely cause is disabled macros.

---

You may try moving your file to a trusted location:

You can see the trusted locations by doing Click File > Options then 
Click Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations.

See [Change macro security settings in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Change-macro-security-settings-in-Excel-3b5ec213-efcc-4d48-9efd-83d097397a7e) [2010].

---

You may also try changing the security settings:

In Excel 2007

- Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options.
- Click Trust Center.
- Click Trust Center Settings.
- Click Macro Settings.
- Click to select the Trust access to the VBA project object model check box.
- Click OK to close the Excel Options dialog box.

Source: [You may receive an run-time error when you programmatically allow access to a Visual Basic project in Excel 2003 and in Excel 2007 - at Microsoft Knowledge base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813969).

---

Note: optional parameters in C# are a relatively new feature... you may try the old way and use `Type.Missing` to fill the infamous 30 args of the [Run method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff197132.aspx). Something like this:

```
xlApp.Run('macro', Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```